# Anywhere in Torah speak about specific professions being praiseworthy and why?

Tags: employment, parnassah-livelihood

Are there any professions the Torah considers praiseworthy and why?

Comment: How explicit a praise are you looking for? If Yaakov blesses his son and says "you will be X" is X a praiseworthy profession? If Moshe was a shepherd and Moshe is praiseworthy, is the profession a good one?

Comment: See the last 2 pages of Kidushin that describe professions the Torah considers praiseworthy and why.

Comment: Please clarify "Torah". The Talmud is also "Torah", and IIRC, it does mention "praiseworthy" occupations. Please describe "praiseworthy", as well. (My *shviger*  "praises" almost everything that I do, but that may not be "praiseworthy".)

Comment: If you explain more precisely what you're looking for, as described in the above comments, and also what you're trying to get at by looking for that, you can make this question much more answerable.

Comment: by Torah I mean all of Torah including תורה שבכתב and תורה שבעל פה by praiseworthy I mean does the Torah give any reason this might be a preferred job to have for any reason?

Answer (score 6):

As noted by Danny Schoemann in a comment, [Kiddushin 82a - 82b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.82a.8?lang=bi) lists some professions that are seen as praiseworthy (along with others that are not):

1. Camel drivers (according to R. Yehudah) - because they work in the dangerous desert where they fear for their lives, and therefore their 'hearts are broken towards G-d'. (Rashi)
2. Sailors - because they work in an even more fear-inducing environment than camel drivers. (Rashi)
3. Embroiderers - because it is a clean and easy trade.
4. Perfumers - as one is dealing with pleasant-smelling materials.

Comment: You missed the most important one - רבי נהוראי אומר מניח אני כל אומנות שבתורה ואיני מלמד בני אלא תורה

Comment: I was unsure whether to include that or not. My read of R Nehorai is that Torah is not a profession at all. He's saying he wouldn't teach his son any profession, but instead would teach him Torah.

Comment: What, you don’t get paid in Kollel? :) That last line in the Gemara is unclear to me, where he explains his reasoning: is he fully comparing learning Torah to a profession, or is he only contrasting the two?

Comment: Is there anyone who discusses these types of careers and how they would translate into more common applications of work today?